# Bind ComboBox Text to a ValidationRule inside another ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I would like to bind the text from ComboBox CB1 to the Validation Rule (CommunicationMode) in ComboBox CB2.
My source code looks like this, but I get the error: "Binding" can only be set for a "DependencyProperty" of a "DependencyObject".
Is there a way to solve this?

```
    public string CommunicationMode { get; set; }
    
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }


<ComboBox Name="CB1">
    <ComboBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="CB1" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </ComboBox.Text>
 </ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="CB2">
    <ComboBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="CB2" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <valid:ComboboxValidationRule CommunicationMode="{Binding ElementName=CB1, Path=Name}" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.Text>
 </ComboBox>
```

Comment: In `{Binding ElementName=CB1, Path=Name}`, shouldn't the Binding be on `Text` instead of `Name`?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `Wrapper` class with a dependency property:

```
public class ComboboxValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        //your validation logic...
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }

    public Wrapper Wrapper { get; set; }
}

public class Wrapper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommunicationModeProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CommunicationMode), typeof(string), typeof(Wrapper));

    public string CommunicationMode
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CommunicationModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommunicationModeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="CB2">
    <ComboBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="CB2" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <valid:ComboboxValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True">
                    <valid:ComboboxValidationRule.Wrapper>
                        <valid:Wrapper CommunicationMode="{Binding Source={x:Reference CB1}, Path=Name}" />
                    </valid:ComboboxValidationRule.Wrapper>
                </valid:ComboboxValidationRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.Text>
</ComboBox>
```